# ytdl python "KeyError: formats"

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, keyerror, ytdl

Im trying to make a discord music bot for personal use, since groovy and rythm got shut down.
It's working okay-ish I guess, but im having a problem with ytdl.
typing "-play" and an url is working just like intended, but i cant type "-play 'song name'".
Typing "-play example" gives me this:

```
[download] Downloading playlist: example
[youtube:search] query "example": Downloading page 1
[youtube:search] playlist example: Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] CLXt3yh2g0s: Downloading webpage
Ignoring exception in command play:
[download] Finished downloading playlist: example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dennis\PycharmProjects\groovy's true successor\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dennis\PycharmProjects\groovy's true successor\voice.py", line 53, in play
    url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
KeyError: 'formats'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dennis\PycharmProjects\groovy's true successor\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Dennis\PycharmProjects\groovy's true successor\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dennis\PycharmProjects\groovy's true successor\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'formats'
```

im fairly new to coding, so im sorry if somethings weird to understand.

okay, so: typing -play with an url works fine, but typing -play with the song name doesnt. its only searching for the first word, downloads the first searchresult and then "crashes".

so "-play Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up" for example only searches for "Rick" and then it says something about KeyError: 'formats'
Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        pass
    else:
        await channel.connect()

    ffmpeg_opts = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    ydl_opts = {'format': "bestaudio/best", 'default_search': 'auto'}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **ffmpeg_opts)
        vc.play(source)
```

Comment: I assume the error is with the key name. Can you try **info['format']**

Comment: i already tried that. same thing. deleting that part and leaving "[0]['url]" gives me the same error, but with "KeyError: '0'" for example. i think the problem is that its trying to get stuff out of the "ydl.extract_info(url, download=False) line, but it cant extract stuff since it has no url to begin with, its downloading via yt search results and the only thing i have thats close to a link is "yhS9LnDoo_w", the part after "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".

typing "-play test" gives me "[youtube] yhS9LnDoo_w: Downloading webpage" as an output.

Comment: sorry for bad english by the way. english is my third language and im kinda tired.

Answer (score 0):

```
#takes the entire text instead of just the first word
async def play(ctx, *,url):


#i would remove 'default_search': 'auto' and do this
ydl_opts = {'format': "bestaudio/best"}
vc = ctx.voice_client

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    url = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % name, download = False)['entries'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and after a few hours of work on it, I found out that the "extract_info" returns different dictionaries when extracting from a search rather than a url.

I solved this by using a simple if check to differentiate between url and search:

```
#check if it is a valid link
if ("youtube.com" in url or "youtu.be" in url):
#run the normal code after
    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
    source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)

#if it's not a valid link but a search
else:
    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    url2 = info['entries'][0]['webpage_url']
```

This new value of "url2" in the search section will be the link to the video, you should be able to sub this back in to the same thing as with normal links.